# Create Phi-Four Point Matrix Comparing R

Tags: r, matrix, chi-squared

I have a series of binary variables (A to F) that I would like to compare in a Phi Point matrix.

```
       A     B    C      D     E    F
A    1.00                              
B   -0.20  1.00                        
C    0.82 -0.22  1.00                  
D   -0.22  0.22  0.65  1.00            
E    0.00 -0.18 -0.19  0.38  1.00      
F    0.41  0.00 -0.21  0.36  0.09  1.00
```

rcorr() only provides for Pearson's Spearman's and Kendall's Correlation Coefficients

I've been unable to adapt:

```
chisqmatrix <- function(x) {
  names = colnames(x);  num = length(names)
  m = matrix(nrow=num,ncol=num,dimnames=list(names,names))
  for (i in 1:(num-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):num) {
      m[i,j] = chisq.test(x[,i],x[,j],)$p.value
    }
  }
  return (m)
}
mat = chisqmatrix(iris)
```

But this was built on the assumption that only one of the columns is a categorical variable.

Comment: We do not have your data. cannot help